# Prove columns of a Matrix span $\mathbb{Q}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem**: Consider matrix $B =  \left(\begin{smallmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 2 & -1 & 3 \\  1 & 0 & 3 & -2 \\ 
> \end{smallmatrix}\right) $. Show that the columns of this matrix span
>   $\mathbb{Q}^3$ given that $B \in M_{34}(\mathbb{Q})$.

**Attempt**: When you do a RREF, you end up with $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Clearly there are 3 Pivots. Will this be sufficient to say that matrix span $\mathbb{Q}^3$? Do I need anything extra? This question is from the chapter of Linear transformations and I am wondering if I have to use any linear transformation property here.

Comment: This is sufficient. Since the first, second and fourth columns of $B$ are linearly independent, they form a basis for $\Bbb Q^3$, so any set of vectors containing these three columns spans $\Bbb Q^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your row reduction is correct, when you look at  the first, second and fourth columns of your row reduced matrix, these correspond to the three standard basis vectors of $\mathbb Q^3$, since they have a $1$ in precisely one position and zero in all the other positions. Hence, you are correct in saying that the columns of this matrix span $\mathbb Q^3$.

In fact, a slightly stronger statement is true : note that only  the first,second and fourth columns were used to deduce that the column span is $\mathbb Q^3$. Therefore, if you omit the third column of $B$ (that is, create a new matrix which is now $3 \times 3$ with the third column removed), it's columns would still have spanned $\mathbb Q^3$. This would not be true if you would have omitted the fourth column, though.